# How to get looped data from database inside ajax and display it inside selection button by column

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

My problem is that the data that was looped or counted inside my ajax PHP file needs to be displayed inside my selection, I have a static data and needs to compare the static data from a running nested (while)loop, I have difficulties on how will I make the data that is being looped, be selected according to it's conditioned/compared data. I have a comparison or checking of data however it is not working. What I have tried is doing it through a ternary condition and the output is empty or null. When I put `selected` data attribute and then `console.log()` the response in my success call, it shows all the looped data but in my selection it displays only the last value of the loop result.

Here is the console.log(response)

[image]

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var l_id = document.getElementById("id");
var lid = l_id.value;

if (lid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "serial_child_edit.php",
            data: {
                "model_cont": lid
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $("select[name='item0[]']").html(response).selectpicker('refresh');
            }
      });
   }
});
```

Ajax code

```
<?php 

include ('../include/connect.php');


if(isset($_POST['model_cont'])){

    $ID = $_POST['model_cont'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT rbg_lot_details.subid,rbg_lot.id, GROUP_CONCAT(rbg_lot_details.lot_id SEPARATOR ',')as lot_id
    FROM rbg_lot
    LEFT JOIN rbg_lot_details ON rbg_lot.id=rbg_lot_details.subid
    WHERE rbg_lot.id='$ID'");

        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $sub_id = $row['subid'];
        $lot_id = $row['lot_id'];
        $lot = explode("," ,$lot_id);
        $count= count($lot);

        $con->next_result();
        $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT rbg_lot_details.id,rbg_lot_details.subid
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(rbg_lot_serial.serialno SEPARATOR ',')AS serial
        FROM rbg_lot_serial
        LEFT JOIN rbg_lot_details ON rbg_lot_serial.rbg_lot_id=rbg_lot_details.id
        WHERE rbg_lot_details.id='$lot[0]'");
        $rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

        $serial = $rows['serial'];
        $ser = explode("," ,$serial);
        $count= count($ser);            

        // for ($col=0; $col <= $count; $col++)
        // {
        //     echo $lot[$col]; 
        $con->next_result();
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT modeltableformodellotregistration.lot_id as lotid ,modeltableformodellotregistration.serial_start,
        modeltableformodellotregistration.serial_end,model.model_name,category.category,lot_registration.lotno
        FROM modeltableformodellotregistration
        LEFT JOIN category on modeltableformodellotregistration.cat_id=category.cat_id
        LEFT JOIN model on modeltableformodellotregistration.model_id=model.id
        LEFT JOIN lot_registration on modeltableformodellotregistration.lot_id=lot_registration.id
        where  modeltableformodellotregistration.lot_id='$lot[0]'");                                  
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {  
                        $serstart = $row["serial_start"];
                        $serend = $row["serial_end"];  

                            while($serstart <= $serend){

                            echo "
                            <option value='". $serstart."'  ".($serstart == $ser[0] ? 'selected' : '')." >". $serstart."</option>";
                            $serstart++;
                            }   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "0 results";
                }    
                    if ($con->connect_error){
                        die("Connection Failed".$con->connect_error);
                };                                    

        }
   // }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi, what does `console.log(response)` giving you ? Please show output of that .

Comment: Hi! @Swati I will update the question and post an image

Comment: Updated it :) @Swati

Comment: Okay so data are coming right or not ? Also , please elaborate this `my selection it displays only the last value of the loop result...` ?

Comment: Ahhh yes my selection when I do this code `<option value='". $serstart."'  ".($serstart ? 'selected' : '')." >". $serstart."</option>";` let us say 1-20, it displays the 20 but inside my select element all of the data from console.log is there

Comment: this you are talking about `$("select[name='item0[]']")` select-box ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229805/discussion-between-swati-and-error-401).

Comment: @Swati yes yes you are correct :)